# C# read value from web, and create foreach

Tags: c#, web

I have this code, ant it's working fine:

```
FileNameAndSizes.Add("file1.dll", 17662);
FileNameAndSizes.Add("file2.dll", 19019);
```

But I wan't to give it from my web (http://example.com/dll_files.ini)

In my dll_files.ini :

```
file1.dll,17662
file2.dll,19019
```

I know that I must use foreach. I'm created this code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://example.com/dll_files.ini");
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

**I wan't to give value from dll_files.ini and remake value to FileNameAndSizes.Add("file1.dll", 17662); FileName...**

What's next? Help please, I'm newbie in C#, thanks so much, P.S I'm not english
P.S.S is exists faster method to get value from web? Because streamreader ~2sec loading

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the string `content` which you are receiving from web?

Comment: In my dll_files.ini :

file1.dll,17662
file2.dll,19019

Comment: I have edited the answer asssuming you have `"file1.dll,17662\nfile2.dll,19019";` format. try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
        Dictionary<string, long> FileNameAndSizes = new Dictionary<string, long>();
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://example.com/dll_files.ini");
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        String content = reader.ReadToEnd();

        var splitsByLine = content.Split('\n'); //Assuming contents has "file1.dll,17662\nfile2.dll,19019";
        foreach (var s in splitsByLine)
        {
            var nameAndSize = s.Split(',');
            FileNameAndSizes.Add(nameAndSize[0], Convert.ToInt64(nameAndSize[1]));
        }
```

Traversing...

```
foreach (var fileNameAndSize in FileNameAndSizes)
        {
            var name = fileNameAndSize.Key;
            var size = fileNameAndSize.Value;                
            //Other something ...
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not that, I need to get value from my web file, and these "file1.dll,17662
file2.dll,19019" replace to FileNameAndSizes.Add("file.1", 17662);

Comment: @EvaldasL Is your web returns string just like as an example `file1.dll,1214,file2.dll,4545` etc?

Comment: yep, and I wan't to create FileNameAndSizes.Add(firstvalue);
FileNameAndSizes.Add(secondvalue);
etc..
//firstvalue is file1.dll,1214
//secondvalue is file2.dll,4545